# get statistics of dag run times

Tags: statistics, report, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

i'm trying to export dag statistics out of Airflow. the statsd output is not very useful, so i decided to basically run a dag to query the SQL and export it out to say influxdb.

so it's easy enough to create a DAG to query the postgres airflow database. however, i'm a little stumped at the schema. i would have thought:

```
select run_id, start_date, end_date from dag_run where dag_id= 'blah';
```

would do it, but end `end_date` never appears to be populated.

all i'm really after is the total time from which the dag run started (where the first job is initiated as opposed to when the job is first put into a `running` state) and the time the dag went into a `success` state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try hitting the `task_instance` table:

```sql
  SELECT  execution_date
       ,  MIN(start_date) AS start
       ,  MAX(end_date) AS end
       ,  MAX(end_date) - MIN(start_date) AS duration
    FROM  task_instance
   WHERE  dag_id = 'blah'
     AND  state = 'success'
GROUP BY  execution_date
ORDER BY  execution_date DESC
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how can we capture the same MAX(end_date) while implementing same concept in Python script

Comment: @Ravi just any Python script, or one that will be executed with Airflow available and all pertinent configuration?

Comment: We have few dags and want to capture maximum end date of each dag .  How can we keep that functionality in python script which we will use to code the dag and run it on daily basis.. Can you help me with some suggestion

Comment: You'll want to open a question and describe your request. It looks like using the Aiflow code can help you get there: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b43f90abf4c7219d5d59cccb0514256bd3f2fdc7/airflow/models/dag.py#L71